# How to URLEncode a partial encoded text in Java?

Tags: java, urlencode, url-encoding

If the following string is what I want to url-encode,

```
@test123: http://news.yahoo.com/fifa%E6%96%A5%E8%B3%87%E5%8D%83%E8%90%AC-%E5%8A%A9%E6%88%91%E8%B6%B3%E7%90%83%E5%8D%87%E7%B4%9A-185314701.html check out the news.
```

I tried to url-encode the full string but it still url-encode the following url-encoded part of the string.

```
http://news.yahoo.com/fifa%E6%96%A5%E8%B3%87%E5%8D%83%E8%90%AC-%E5%8A%A9%E6%88%91%E8%B6%B3%E7%90%83%E5%8D%87%E7%B4%9A-185314701.html
```

And it caused the server failed to identify the request.

How should I accomplish this?

Comment: What is 'text' here, and what the 'encoded address'? Please clarify your question. Cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: Sorry I've changed the question and found the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode it all, and then encode it.

Also, if it is already encoded, why are you trying to encode it again?

Comment: The reason is because i don't know if there will be an encoded url mixed up in the entire text.

Comment: Hi, I checked the % string. And if the string contains the "%", I decode the full string and encode it again. Now it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is going to be to better manage where you are getting the different components of your url, and not mixing and matching encoded and unencoded strings.  Your post is confusing as well in that the entire url you listed is encoded.  That is to say, there are no elements of that url that are not ASCII.

Comment: The url is encoded, but I still need to encode the entire text. Also I can't control the text. It's mixed up already.